# Format Exception when fetching data from API in flutter

Tags: api, flutter

I've been getting this

`"formatexception (formatexception: unexpected character (at line 8, character 1) <!doctype html><html class="no-js" lang="en"><head>"`

error and my app crashes out.
I'm trying to get news data from  "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=ph&apiKey=aae937474dd8475ca6d45d403cbcd71c" API.
It previously worked but now i'm getting that exception error.

This is my future code where jsondecode is here. It errors on jsonDecode part of the code.

```
    String url =
        "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=ph&apiKey=aae937474dd8475ca6d45d403cbcd71c";
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (jsonData["status"] == "ok") {
      jsonData["articles"].forEach((element) {
        if (element["urlToImage"] != null && element["description"] != null) {
          news.add(
            Article(
              title: element["title"],  
              imgUrl: element["urlToImage"],
              author: element["author"],
              url: element["url"],
              description: element["description"],
              content: element["content"],
              publishedAt: DateTime.parse(element["publishedAt"]),
            ),
          );
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That usually happens when an http request is invalid and the website redirects itself either to an error page or to the main page, or even the closest path. It is weird as the error is not happening on my case. Type the link itself on your browser as it should appear actual html

Comment: The API is active and good. but when I decode it in flutter it crases out. Anything I would do to make this exception vanish? @AntónioOliveira

Comment: tested it and code works fine.

Comment: @MJMontes bro it crashes on my side. i've done already flutter clean. restarted my device. and still the same

Answer (score 0):

Your request returning Error Page
Please check this example which will get news from NewsAPI
https://rrtutors.com/tutorials/Flutter-NewsApplication-ListVew-Search-Filter

Comment: do I need to rework all my code or just need to change the API key?